# Simulates flipping a coin repeatedly and continues until however many consecutive heads are tossed

Tags: java, random, simulation

This program simulates flipping a coin repeatedly and continues until however many consecutive heads are tossed.

I'm wondering if there are any issues when initializing a variable in a `for` loop the way I did. Also I assume assigning `-1` to `i` was an appropriate move as well because after a loop cycle it will iterate (`i++`) causing `i` to become `1` if I had not, resulting in one less loop.

```
/*
 * File: ConsecutiveHeads.java
 * ---------------------------
 * This program simulates flipping a coin 
 * repeatedly and continues until however many
 * consecutive heads are tossed.
 */

/* Library packages */
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;

public class ConsecutiveHeads extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {
        int flips = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < CONSECUTIVE_HEADS; i++) {
            String coinSide = flipCoin();
            println(coinSide);
            flips++;
            if (coinSide.equals("Tails")) {
                i = -1;
            }
        }
        println("It took " + flips + " flips to "
                + "get " + CONSECUTIVE_HEADS + " consecutive heads.");
    }

    /* Returns true 50% of the time */
    private String flipCoin() {
        return rgen.nextBoolean() ? "Tails" : "Heads";
    }

    /* Create an instance variable for the random number generator */
    private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();

    /* Private constant */
    private static final int CONSECUTIVE_HEADS = 3;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more readable to just use a while loop and reset the `headsCount` after a tails.

Comment: I’m assuming this is a theoretical example, and you’re not interested in a pragmatic solution or optimisations? There’s a [closed formula solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) to this problem, which would decimate both your running time and code size. For these reasons, in practice you wouldn’t want to use a loop here.

Comment: I personally wouldn't do `String` comparison inside your loop; you're really just assigning a `String` value to a `boolean` value then evaluating it to `boolean` anyway. I would invert your True:False = Tails:Heads to True:False = Heads:Tails, then you just do `flips++; if (rgen.nextBoolean()) { i++; println('Heads'); continue; } i = 0; println('Tails');`but i'll be honest, that's probably splitting hairs.

Comment: What was the idea behind converting a boolean to a string?

Comment: @user1993392 I'm a novice. I'm was thinking that it makes it more "readable" but obviously that does not fit. I am aware my thoughts on my code are not what they should be. From the responses I get here I am learning what is bad and not necessary and what to include.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## for loop

I find both, your solution and the approach of @BenC difficult to understand.

I'd suggest to use a `while` loop instead:

```
int consecutiveHeads = 0
while (consecutiveHeads < consecutiveHeadsThreshold) {
  CoinSide toss = flipCoin();
  flips++;
  println(toss.getName());

  if (CoinSide.HEADS.equals(toss)) {
    consecutiveHeads++;
  } else {
    consecutiveHeads = 0;
  }
}
```

Or you are consequent with your abuse of the `for` loop:

```
public void run(final int consecutiveHeadsThreshold) {
    int flips = 0;
    for (int consecutiveHeads = 0;
             consecutiveHeads < consecutiveHeadsThreshold;
             consecutiveHeads = doFlip(consecutiveHeads )){
        flip++;  
    }
   // ...
}

private int doFlip(int consecutiveHeads) {
  CoinSide toss = flipCoin();
  println(toss.getName());
  if (CoinSide.HEADS.equals(toss)) {
    consecutiveHeads++;
  } else {
    consecutiveHeads = 0;
  }
  return consecutiveHeads;
}
```

Comment: While I agree that it's practically a while loop already, I don't see how the for loop is any harder to understand -- it's just where you place the `consecutiveHeads` var, inside or outside the loop scope.

Comment: @BenC `for` loops implies that the number of iterations is somehow *determined before entering the loop* whereas *while* implies that we iterate an *unknown number of times* until a condition is meet. Maybe its just me, but I have a strange feeling by using a `for`in this case...

Comment: I don't share that mental model / semantic distinction (I see a `for` loop as just a loop with three statements, all optional, and which provides the ability to constrain the scope of loop vars), but I understand where you're coming from, cheers.

Comment: I agree it's "strange" to see the counter of the for loop changed.  And setting `consecutiveHeads = 0;` seems more logical than `i = -1`.

Comment: I don’t think I’ve seen a for loop used like that before, so for me it took extra brain-cycles to understand. A while loop wouldn’t have that issue

Answer (score 11):

#### Loop

> Also i assume assigning -1 to i was an appropriate move as well because after a loop cycle it will iterate (i++) causing i to become 1 if I had not, resulting in one less loop.

Well, that works, but I think it would be more clear to explicitly increment `i` on heads, and reset it otherwise:

```
for (int consecutiveHeads = 0; consecutiveHeads < CONSECUTIVE_HEADS_THRESHOLD;) {
  ...
  if (coinSide.equals("Heads")) {
    consecutiveHeads++;
  } else {
    consecutiveHeads = 0;
  }
}
```

That could be a while loop as well, depending on your tastes.

#### Comments

> ```
> /* Create an instance variable for the random number generator */
> ```

This is not really necessary. It's clearly an instance variable, and the names and types show that it is a RNG.

> ```
> /* Private constant */
> ```

Again, this isn't really necessary. `private final` already shows that is is a private constant. Even if you these comments are more intended for organization, a common approach would be to group these variables in blocks at the top of the class, with implicit meaning.

They don't take away from anything, they're just not really necessary.

> ```
> /* Returns true 50% of the time */
> private String flipCoin() {
> ```

This is not accurate. It will never return `true`. It returns strings.

#### Matching strings

Matching against strings is somewhat fragile. If this was a larger codebase, you would probably implement an enum for the coin sides, although it's overkill for this example. Altogether, a slightly more genericized version might look something like this:

```
public class ConsecutiveHeads extends ConsoleProgram {

  // These traditionally go up top, not at the bottom of the class.
  private final RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
  private static final int DEFAULT_CONSECUTIVE_HEADS_THRESHOLD = 3;

  public void run() {
    run(DEFAULT_CONSECUTIVE_HEADS_THRESHOLD);
  }

  // Theshold is parameterized
  public void run(final int consecutiveHeadsThreshold) {
    int flips = 0;
    for (int consecutiveHeads = 0; consecutiveHeads < consecutiveHeadsThreshold;) {
      CoinSide toss = flipCoin();
      flips++;
      println(toss.getName());

      if (CoinSide.HEADS.equals(toss)) {
        consecutiveHeads++;
      } else {
        consecutiveHeads = 0;
      }
    }
    System.out.printf("It took %d flips to get %d consecutive heads.", flips, consecutiveHeadsThreshold);
  }

  private CoinSide flipCoin() {
    return CoinSide.from(rgen.nextBoolean());
  }

  // Alternatively, in the limited scope of this example, you could
  // just define `true` to be heads and then not bother defining tails
  // at all.
  enum CoinSide {
    HEADS("Heads"), TAILS("Tails");

    private final String name;
    CoinSide(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public static CoinSide from(bool value) { return value ? HEADS : TAILS; }
  }
}
```

Comment: For `for`-loops with omitted terms, I'd be sorely tempted to do something like `for (int i = 0; i < X; /* explain why this is missing */) {...`

Comment: If you use `enum` you can use `==`. Or `switch` and `case`. Both are more readable than the `if (Enum.ENUMVALUE.equals(testValue))`

Comment: Don't forget a %n in the printf to also print a new line.